# php log in form does not respond

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying what should be a pretty easy loginn form to a localhost database, but when I push log in it doesn't do anything. Basically I just get as input a username and password and try to get the data (I know the url looks weird as uid=password but it is as it has to be).

Then I compare what the database should return (name and uid) and compare those fields. Any hint would be of great help!

```
 <?php
        $log = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/users?uid=$password");
        $data = json_decode($log);
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        
        if($log.empty) {
          header("Location: inici.html");
          exit;
        }
        
        if(($username == $data->Nombre) && ($password == $data->UID)){
          header("Location: inici.html");
          exit;
        }
        else
        {
          header("Location: login.html");
          exit;
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

At first you write:

```
$data = json_decode($log);
```

and then you produce a run-time error with illegal/meaningless syntax:

```
if($log.empty) {
```

`$log` is a string, while you might have meant the `$data` `array` or `object`. In PHP there is only an `->` object-access operator ... the `.` operator just concatenates.

You could check for: `if(! empty($log))` to determine an empty response.

Comment: And what is the response of the server?

Comment: None at all, like it didn't notice anything

Comment: Error reporting might be disabled in `php.ini`. It should at least send the `Location` headers, when there was no error.

Comment: And how can I enable it?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ...that's the least required in order to understand what is even going on. [xdebug](https://xdebug.org) is also quite useful (it is being supported in most IDE, alike NetBeans, VSCode, PHPStorm, etc).